# count multiple columns in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

Guys i have four queries:

Query #1:

```
select 
satisfaction_score,count(satisfaction_score) as Satisfaction_count
from j_survey_response
where satisfaction_score != 0
group by satisfaction_score
```

The output will be

```
satisfaction_score    Satisfaction_count
1                           5
2                           8
3                          97
4                         329
5                         859
```

Query #2:

```
select 
response_score,count(response_score) as response_count
from j_survey_response
where response_score != 0
group by response_score
```

OUTPUT

```
response_score  response_count
1                    28
2                     8
3                    42
4                   250
5                   980
```

Query #3:

```
select 
responder_score,count(responder_score) as responder_count
from j_survey_response
where responder_score != 0
group by responder_score
```

OUTPUT

```
responder_score  responder_count
1                     24
2                      3
3                     30
4                    236
5                    987
```

Query #4:

```
select 
service_score,count(service_score) as service_count
from j_survey_response
where service_score != 0
group by service_score
```

OUTPUT

```
service_score    service_count
1                     22
2                      2
3                     34
4                    270
5                    966
```

But I need the output as below

```
score  satisfaction_count  response_count  responder_count  service_count
1            5                  28              24               22
2            8                   8               3                2
3           97                  42              30               34
4          329                 250             236              270
5          859                 980             986              966
```

Comment: Can't you show us some sample table data as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `UNION ALL` the separate queries and apply *conditional* aggregation on the resulting set:

```
select score,
       max(case when type = 'satisfaction' then count end) as satisfaction_count,
       max(case when type = 'response' then count end) as response_count,
       max(case when type = 'responder' then count end) as responder_count,
       max(case when type = 'service' then count end) as service_count             
from (
  select satisfaction_score as score, 
         count(satisfaction_score) as count, 
         'satisfaction' as type
  from j_survey_response
  where satisfaction_score != 0
  group by satisfaction_score

  union all

  select response_score,
         count(response_score) as count, 'response' as type
  from j_survey_response
  where response_score != 0
  group by response_score

  union all

  select responder_score,
         count(responder_score) as count, 'responder' as type
  from j_survey_response
  where responder_score != 0
  group by responder_score

  union all

  select service_score,
         count(service_score) as count, 'service' as type
  from j_survey_response
  where service_score != 0
  group by service_score) as t
group by score
```

Comment: what if value of 1 is not present in the satisfaction_score column? The output will start from second column only

Comment: @JeevaBalan Yes, this is correct. If the value is absent from *all tables* then the value will not appear in the final result. You need a numbers table in this case that holds all possible score values. Using this table you can then left join the tables from the query above.

Comment: I tried above query but it shows error 1604: error in sql syntax at line 2 near ')'

Answer (score 1):

Move them in subqueries and join them by score columns. Like this

```
select 
   q1.satisfaction_score as score,
   q1.satisfaction_count,
   q2.response_count,
   q3.responder_count ,
   q4.service_count,
from (query 1) q1
     join (query 2) q2 on q1.satisfaction_score=q2.response_score
     join (query 3) q3 on q1.satisfaction_score=q3.responder_score
     join (query 4) q4 on q1.satisfaction_score=q3.service_score
```

Comment: What if a score bucket is empty in one of the four subqueries?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos for the posted output is fine. It may need full join in common case. But actually its better to define a separate table with required scores values and left join all the subqueries with the scores dataset

Comment: It shows error Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: I've added the missing table aliases.

Comment: We join all the rows by score values. So for row with score=1 in the first subquery we have corresponding rows in the q2, q3, q4 and just use their calculated values.

Comment: what if value of 1 is not present in the satisfaction_score column? The output will start from second column only

Answer (score 0):

You Try this Sql Query

```
select service_score , count(satisfaction_score) as Satisfaction_count,
count(response_score) as response_count,count(responder_score) as `responder_count,
count(service_score) as service_count from j_survey_response
where service_score != 0 and responder_score != 0 and response_score != 0 and satisfaction_score != 0`
```

if you use group by

```
select service_score , count(satisfaction_score) as Satisfaction_count,
count(response_score) as response_count,count(responder_score) as `responder_count,
count(service_score) as service_count from j_survey_response
where service_score != 0 and responder_score != 0 and response_score != 0 and satisfaction_score != 0` 
group by satisfaction_score,response_score,responder_score,service_score
```