# count multiple columns in a query

Tags: mysql

Guys i have four queries:

Query #1:

```
select 
satisfaction_score,count(satisfaction_score) as Satisfaction_count
from j_survey_response
where satisfaction_score != 0
group by satisfaction_score
```

The output will be

```
satisfaction_score    Satisfaction_count
4                         329
5                         859
```

Query #2:

```
select 
response_score,count(response_score) as response_count
from j_survey_response
where response_score != 0
group by response_score
```

OUTPUT

```
response_score  response_count
3                    42
5                   980
```

Query #3:

```
select 
responder_score,count(responder_score) as responder_count
from j_survey_response
where responder_score != 0
group by responder_score
```

OUTPUT

```
responder_score  responder_count
4                    236
5                    987
```

Query #4:

```
select 
service_score,count(service_score) as service_count
from j_survey_response
where service_score != 0
group by service_score
```

OUTPUT

```
service_score    service_count
5                    966
```

But I need the output as below

```
score  satisfaction_count  response_count  responder_count  service_count
3         null                  42            null             null
4          329                null             236             null
5          859                 980             986              966
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Looks pretty similar to one of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431072/count-multiple-columns-in-one-query

Comment: Similar to that only but if that will return only the fifth column in this input

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
select score,
        max(if(score_type='satisfaction_score',count,null)) as satisfaction_count,
        max(if(score_type='response_score',count,null)) as response_count,
        max(if(score_type='responder_score',count,null)) as responder_count,
        max(if(score_type='service_score',count,null)) as service_count
from (
    select score,count(satisfaction_score) as count,'satisfaction_score' as score_type from j_survey_response where satisfaction_score != 0 group by satisfaction_score
    union all
    select score,count(response_score) ,'response_score' as score_type from j_survey_response where response_score != 0 group by response_score
    union all
    select score,count(responder_score) ,'responder_score' as score_type from j_survey_response where responder_score != 0 group by responder_score
    union all
    select score,count(service_score) ,'service_score' as score_type from j_survey_response where service_score != 0 group by service_score
) as scores
group by scores.score
```